# What means IO$,IF$,$ in CFG

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar, finite-automata, context-free-language, automata-theory

Parse the expression: `IF i> i THEN i = i + i * i`
using the following CFG definition of a small programming language,

```
S → ASSIGNMENT$| GOTO$| IF$| IO$
ASSIGNMENT$ → i = ALEX
GOTO$ → GOTO NUMBER
IF$ → IF CONDITION THEN S
    | IF CONDITION THEN S ELSE S
CONDITION → ALEX = ALEX| ALEX ≠ ALEX| ALEX > ALEX
          | CONDITION AND CONDITION
          | CONDITION OR CONDITION
          | NOT CONDITION
IO$ → READ i| PRINT i
```

HINTS:

1. ALEX stands for algebraic expression
2. the names end in $ are class
3. the terminals are `{ = GOTO IF THEN ELSE ≠ > AND OR NOT READ PRINT }`
4. whatever terminals are introduced in the definitions of `i`, `ALEX`, and `NUMBER`.

Comment: Where is this taken from? Can you show us the original?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like '$' is an abbreviation for 'STATEMENT'. E.g., "IF$" means "IF STATEMENT".

But regardless of what it "means", you can treat it as if it were an ordinary letter for the purpose of the exercise: "IF$" is just the name of a non-terminal that occurs in the grammar.